# Clicking Children Item in Sliding Panel triggers parent first?

Tags: android, android-sliding

I am using sliding panel layout and in that i have ONE floating buttons.Now when i Click on the button the view Slides first and then i have to click again on button to perform action.

I want to perform action on only single click without the sliding movement of parent view.

Look at these images
[Look at 1 images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD212.png)
[look at this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc1M9.png)
Here is my

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout           
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/Sliding"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/leftSide"
        android:background="#ef3"
        >

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/contact"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_key"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:id="@+id/rightSide"
    android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:id="@+id/call"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/message" />

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

here is my java code

```
SlidingPaneLayout sp;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    context = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    call = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.call);

    sp = (SlidingPaneLayout) findViewById(R.id.Sliding);
    assert sp != null;
    sp.setPanelSlideListener(this);
    sp.setSliderFadeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    sp.openPane();
    mList = new ArrayList<Contacts>();

    call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.e("CALL","CALL");
            try
            {
                if(number.isEmpty())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Please select contact first",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    calling();
                    number=null;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context,"This is not the valid contact",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can u be more specific ?

Comment: I have a sliding panel in which i have a button.Sliding Panel is closed initially and a button is visible to the user. so when i click on button the sliding panel opens up instead of performing the action written in onClick of button.
and when the 2nd time i click the onClick of button works but doesn't work on 1st click.
so the thing is my onClick of button doesn't work on 1st click  @W4R10CK

Comment: do u want the code run and slide open same time ?

Comment: no i just want the code run  when user clicks on button

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/Sliding"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/leftSide"
    android:background="#ef3"
    >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/contact"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_key"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:id="@+id/rightSide"
    android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:id="@+id/call"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but there is no sliding panel in this.
I tried the code the view is not sliding

Comment: No sliding panel in this means ?

Comment: look at the screenshots attached in question @W4R10CK